# Laravel 6.x Policy not being called after authorize (No Middleware)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I am having some problems with Laravel 6 policies. I get 403 unauthorized all the time even though it should be a non-authenticated request.

Files:

**api.php**

```
Route::prefix('v2')
  ->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('agencies')->group(function () {
            Route::post('/', 'Api\AgencyController@store');
        });
    }
```

**AgencyController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Entities\Agency;

class AgencyController extends Controller {
    public function store(AgencyRequest $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Agency::class);

        // Code that is never executed
    }
}
```

**AgencyPolicy.php**

```
class AgencyPolicy
{
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        \Log::info('hello?'); // This Log is never executed
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        \App\Entities\Agency::class => \App\Policies\AgencyPolicy::class,
        // Other policies
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::before(function ($user) {
            if ($user->hasRole(SuperAdmin::ROLE_NAME)) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        Passport::routes(null,  ['prefix' => 'api/oauth']);
    }
}
```

My code is identical to the documentation but nonetheless I keep getting 403 unauthorized, and for the life of me I cannot understand what is going on. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: is `Agency` aliased correctly in `AgencyController` ... and if it is a 'non-authenticated' request then it will always fail this authorization

Comment: It is, let me edit the question.

Comment: @lagbox, why should it always fail the request?

Comment: its directly in the docs "By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user." please read the section about Guest users - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#guest-users

Comment: It is that indeed. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lagbox thankfully [replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390524/laravel-6-x-policy-not-being-called-after-authorize-no-middleware?noredirect=1#comment104972614_59390524), the answer is in the documentation, that states:

> By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user. However, you may allow these authorization checks to pass through to your gates and policies by declaring an "optional" type-hint or supplying a null default value for the user argument definition:

Thus, my problem would be solved by using `?User` in **AgencyPolicy.php**:

```
class AgencyPolicy
{
    public function create(?User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: @lagbox I can only do that after 2 days